Ratio of real world to risk-neutral density
Suppose I have a risk-neutral pdf and a real-world pdf of an asset. Both functions are related by a scaling factor or the sdf which would transform the risk-neutral into the real-world density, is this correct? Would I be able to obtain this scaling factor by simply computing the ratio of the RW/RN density across X? If not, why?

The ratio of any two PDFs (if it can be defined: see below) is just the Radon-Nikodym derivative. The conditions for the Radon-Nikodym derivative to exist are given by the Radon-Nikodym theorem.
Whilst on a first read basis, the rigorous phrasing of the theorem might sound a bit abstract / difficult, the intuition is easy. The theorem says that given two probability measures $\mathbb{P}_1$ and $\mathbb{P}_2$, the Radon-Nikodym derivative $\frac{\partial\mathbb{P}_2}{\partial\mathbb{P}_1}$ exists if the two measures agree on "what is possible", which means they agree on where probabilities are zero and where they are non-zero (see footnote*).
Example 1:
Consider two log-normal random variables $X$ and $Y$, where:
$$\ln{(X)}\sim N\left(\mu -0.5 \sigma^2, \sigma\right), \quad \ln{(Y)}\sim N\left(r -0.5 \sigma^2, \sigma\right)$$
Let the PDF of $X$ be $f_X$ and the PDF of $Y$ be $f_Y$ (and the associated probability measures induced by $X$ and $Y$ are $\mathbb{P}_X$ and $\mathbb{P}_Y$). Note that the support of $X$ and $Y$ are the same: specifically the two random variables have positive densities on the real-line for $x>0$, whilst their densities are zero for $x\leq0$: therefore, these two random variables "agree on what is possible" (any $x>0$): they just assign slightly different probabilities to these outcomes. So the conditions for the Radon-Nikodym derivative to exist are satisfied and we can write:
$$\frac{\partial\mathbb{P}_Y}{\partial\mathbb{P}_X}=\frac{f_Y}{f_X}$$
Example 2:
Consider now a log-normal random variable $X$ and a normal random variable $Z$, where:
$$\ln{(X)}\sim N\left(\mu -0.5 \sigma^2, \sigma\right), \quad Z\sim N\left(\mu -0.5 \sigma^2, \sigma\right)$$
The problem here is that $Z$ has positive densities across the entire real line $\mathbb{R}$ whilst $X$ only has positive densities for $x>0$. So for the case where we want to go from $\mathbb{P}_X$ to $\mathbb{P}_Z$, the conditions for the Radon-Nikodym theorem are not satisfied and the Radon-Nikodym derivative does not exist. Indeed, if we tried to compute the ratio of the two PDFs, we would run into the following issues:
$$\frac{\partial\mathbb{P}_Z}{\partial\mathbb{P}_X}=\frac{f_Z}{f_X}=??$$
The derivative is clearly undefined $\forall x \leq 0$ due to division by zero.
*Footnote: strictly speaking, for $\frac{d\mathbb{P}_2}{d\mathbb{P}_1}$ to exsist, the theorem states that $\mathbb{P}_2$ must be absolutely continuous w.r.t. $\mathbb{P}_1$, which means that whenever $\mathbb{P}_2(A)=0$ for any $A \in \mathcal{F}$, it implies that $\mathbb{P}_1(A)=0$ (but the converse needs not to be true).

Thanks for the reply. Assuming the Radon-Nikodym derivative exists, how would I go about computing it? Is it a matter of computing the ratio of probabilities for each point on the pdf?

@OttoWinata: if you have the two PDFs expressed as functions, you can just take the ratio of the two functions. Say the risk-neutral PDF (denoted $f^{\mathbb{Q}}_X$
) and the real-world PDF (denoted $f^{\mathbb{P}}_X$) are given as: $$f^{\mathbb{Q}}_X(h)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(h-r)^2}{2\sigma^2}}  \quad f^{\mathbb{P}}_X(h)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(h-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$ Then their ratio is $$e^{\frac{2h(\mu-r)+r^2-\mu^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$ If you only have the PDF at specific points, then indeed you just compute the ratio of the values at each point.

Thanks again. So say I have a list of ratios across the range of X. How would these values relate to Girsanov's theorem where you go from risk-neutral to real-world densities through a change of measure? Would it be a reasonable approach to estimate the change of measure by fitting my data onto the equation laid out by the theorem?

@OttoWinata: do you assume any specific dynamics for your asset? Standard Girsanov assumes log-normal dynamics of the asset (and the therorem is then applied to the Brownian within the GBM).

The idea is that I have the real world density of returns of an asset which is estimated by fitting a kde on return data over a couple years. Then I'd multiply the kde by the radon-nikodym derivative to obtain the risk-neutral density. Does this approach make any sense?

@OttoWinata: I am not an expert on Kernel Density estimation, but your approach sounds reasonable. Once you have the rw density estimated via KDE, multiplying by the R-N derivative should produce the risk-neutral densities.

Thanks a lot! So the RN derivative would be the ratios right? So going back to my previous question, would it be possible to apply Girsanov onto this set of ratios? Performing some estimation of the parameters using the empirical ratios?

@OttoWinata: you can use the ratios to estimate the parameters of the Radon-Nikodym derivative. But what functional form of the Radon-Nikodym derivative do you assume? The "standard Girsanov RN" which is: $$g(W_t^{\mathbb{P}})=\frac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{P}}:=\exp{\left(-W_t^{\mathbb{P}}\tilde{\mu}-0.5\tilde{\mu}^2t\right)}$$
where: $$\tilde{\mu}=\tilde{\mu}:=\frac{\mu -r}{\sigma}$$
assumes a very specific dynamics of the underlying asset (i.e. GBM).

Say I take it for granted that the asset moves in GBM, what set of observations would I use for Wt? For reference my set of ratios were generated from bitcoin returns. To answer your question I'm not sure, that's part of what I'm trying to figure out to see whether there is any sense in applying Girsanov here. It's part of my Master's dissertation.

@OttoWinata: you have the Real-World PDF via KDE. And you also have the Rirsk-Neutral PDF. Their ratios will give you the values of the Radon-Nikodym derivative at various points. You can see from the Real-World PDF what type of PDF it is. If it looks log-normal, you can try to fit the ratios onto the R-N derivative from Girsanov Theorem to estimate the R-N derivative parameters. But if the Real-World density does not look log-normal, then it would be more interesting to try to plot the R-N derivative ratios and try to fit a function through it (different to the R-N derivative from Girsanov).

I see, if say I were to fit the ratios onto the Girsanov RN derivative, what set of observations should I use for Wt? Is it simply running multiple simulations of brownian motion over time t, and taking the final values of each simulation as the observation?
